# Installation of onnx library on conda fails with version problems

Tags: dependencies, installation, conda, onnx, python-3.7

I am trying to install conda for my profile (env?) on Windows machine using `conda install --name ptholeti onnx -c conda-forge`

It fails with dependency/version issues on pip, wheel and wincertstore.

```
<removed output for brevity>
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining setuptools:  <removed output for brevity>

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - onnx -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*']
  - onnx -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

<removed output for brevity>

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package wincertstore conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
onnx -> protobuf=3.5 -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
Package wheel conflicts for:
onnx -> python=3.6 -> pip -> wheel
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip
onnx -> python=3.6 -> pip
Package setuptools conflicts for:
onnx -> protobuf=3.5 -> setuptools
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
Package certifi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
onnx -> protobuf=3.5 -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Similar issues on github had been recommended to create a new env, seemingly because all required were not yet supported on 3.7. But these issues are more than a year old, so I guess I am missing something.

Any help/guidance would be great.

`conda info`:

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\ptholeti\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\ptholeti\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\ptholeti\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\ptholeti\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\ptholeti\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ptholeti\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ptholeti\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\ptholeti\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\ptholeti\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\ptholeti\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some recent updates to the build process in ONNX to address build issues in windows conda environments. Can you follow the instructions from here :
https://github.com/onnx/onnx#instructions-to-build-onnx-on-windows-in-anaconda-environment

Answer (score 0):

You can try downgrading your conda env python version by

```
conda install python=3.6.9
```

or any version <3.7 that works for you. Then install onnx again.